# Get the id of the parent (li) with its content (span). CHEERIO

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

I have a code here which I got by scraping a page:

```html
<div>
    <ul id="options">
        <li id="option-1" data-nume="1">
            <span class="title">Book</span>
            <span class="site">fnac.com</span>
        </li>
        <li id="option-2" data-nume="2">
            <span class="title">TV</span>
            <span class="site">youtube.com</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I would like with cheerio or just Vanilla JS to find the id of the parent (li) with its content (span).

Example:

- Detect the span element **TV**
- Take the id of its parent (here **option-2**)
- Return the value **data-nume**.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `filter()`

https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-selector

```
const $tv = $('#options .title').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase() === 'tv';
});

const tvNume = $tv.parent('[data-nume]').data('nume');

console.log(tvNume);
```

**Working Demo**

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-tree-6hez6?file=/src/index.js